# Need help adding paragraph tags together to make total

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am making an online program for my store, and I am trying to add the paragraph tags to get the total cost. I just get `[object HTMLCollection]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Cash Register</h1>
  //name and price
  <input type="text" id="myText1" value="Name">

  <input type="text" id="myText2" value="Price">

  <button onclick="add()">Add</button>

  <div id="div1">
    <h2 id="demo1">
      <h2 id="demo2"></h2>
  </div>

  <script>
    function add() {
      //my variables
      var x = 'Total:'
      var y = document.getElementById("myText2").value;
      var z = document.getElementById("myText1").value;
      //create the paragraphs  
      var para = document.createElement("h4");
      var node = document.createTextNode('_____');
      para.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById("div1");
      element.appendChild(para);
      var para = document.createElement("h4");
      var node = document.createTextNode(z);
      para.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById("div1");
      element.appendChild(para);
      var para = document.createElement("p");
      var node = document.createTextNode(y);
      para.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById("div1");
      element.appendChild(para);



      //writes "Total (total)"   
      var w = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = w;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

If anyone could help, that would be nice. Here is my result:

[image: result]

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post.

Comment: Because `HTMLCollection` is what `document.getElementsByTagName("p");` returns. For setting `innerHTML` you need the HTML string, not the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new bit of code, replace the portion under //writes total with this.

```
    //writes "Total (total)"   
    var w = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); // this gets all the P's as an object
    // setup a total starting at 0
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
        total += parseInt(w[i].innerText);  // make the inner text an integer for addition.
    }

    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = total;  // replace w with total
```

Your issue is you are getting a collection of elements with

```
var w = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

That has the value of "Object".  Instead you need to loop through that, and add up the values.

Comment: @EthanP great, keep learning and remember SO is here to help.